# How to convert input into asterisk(*) without pressing enter in BlueJ

Tags: java, passwords, bluej

I want to take a password from the user in the Terminal Window of BlueJ. So whatever the user is entering must instantly convert into an asterisk(*). I don't want to take the the input in separate character but as a single string. Please help me. I am using BlueJ. If anything is required pls tell me.

Comment: That's not possible in the BlueJ terminal. You've got to make a GUI thing for that.

Comment: So can we make a GUI thing in BlueJ @progy_rock

Comment: Oh yes! We can!

Comment: so pls tell me how to do that in BlueJ in the answers section

Comment: No. I won't. No one would. We are not here to write code for you or just get your job done for free. We are here to help you in case you face a trouble while coding.

Comment: Actually I am a student studying in standard 10 and need this to submit in my project. And I don't know how to make the GUI. If u want u may help me and I would be very very grateful for that

Comment: Why don't you ask your teacher to help you with that?

Comment: First its holiday time and second my teacher won't help in this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have GUI Extension for Bluej.
And then we have to use JPassword field to convert all the entered alphabets or numbers into asterisk(*).
That's it.